# TableVew - Select and focus clicked cell

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, tableview, javafx-8

I have an event listener on a TableView which listens for mouse events. How can I get the mouse clicked cell index (and change focus to the new cell) when a mouse event is thrown.

```
public class PrnTableController
{
    @FXML
    private TableView<SimpleStringProperty> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SimpleStringProperty, String> data;

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        this.data.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue());
        this.data.setCellFactory(event -> new EditCell(this.observablePrnPropertyData, this.table));

        // Add mouse Listener
        this.table.setOnMouseClicked(event -> this.handleOnMouseClick(event));
    }

    private void handleOnMouseClick(MouseEvent event)
    {
        TableView tv = (TableView) event.getSource();

        // TODO : get the mouse clicked cell index
        int index = ???

        if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
        {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                LOGGER.info("Double clicked on cell");

                final int focusedIndex = this.table.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex();
                if (index == focusedIndex)
                {
                     // TODO : Double click
                }
            }
            else if (event.getClickCount() == 1)
            {
                // TODO : Single click
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have managed to get the clicked cell index when the mouse event is on the Cell but not the table.

The following code can be used to get the clicked cell index when the event is on the Cell. I've had problems with selecting and changing focus when the mouse event is on TabelCell. The focus does not change to the new cell. It changes if you double click. With a single click nothing happens. I suspect thats because I have other event listeners, there may be conflicting events. I have the following event on the TableCell - setOnDragDetected, setOnMouseDragEntered and the following event on the TableView - addEventFilter, setOnKeyPressed, setOnEditCommit.

```
TableCell<Map<String, SimpleStringProperty>, String> cell = (TableCell<Map<String, SimpleStringProperty>, String>) mouseEvent.getSource();
int index = cell.getIndex();
```

Here is an example with the problem. Basically when you click on an cell, you can see that the event is registered but nothing happens. I mean the focus does change to the newly clicked cell.

```
public class TableViewEditOnType extends Application
{
private TableView<Person> table;
private ObservableList<Person> observableListOfPerson;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{

    this.table = new TableView<>();

    this.table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    this.table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Person, String> firstName = this.createColumn("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty);
    TableColumn<Person, String> lastName = this.createColumn("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty);
    TableColumn<Person, String> email = this.createColumn("Email", Person::emailProperty);
    this.table.getColumns().add(firstName);
    this.table.getColumns().add(lastName);
    this.table.getColumns().add(email);

    this.observableListOfPerson = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    this.observableListOfPerson.add(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"));
    this.observableListOfPerson.add(new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"));
    this.observableListOfPerson.add(new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"));
    this.observableListOfPerson.add(new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"));
    this.observableListOfPerson.add(new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));

    this.table.getItems().addAll(this.observableListOfPerson);

    firstName.setOnEditCommit(event -> this.editCommit(event, "firstName"));
    lastName.setOnEditCommit(event -> this.editCommit(event, "lastName"));
    email.setOnEditCommit(event -> this.editCommit(event, "email"));

    this.table.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        TablePosition<Person, ?> pos = this.table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        if (pos != null)
        {
            this.table.edit(pos.getRow(), pos.getTableColumn());
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(this.table), 880, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void editCommit(CellEditEvent<Person, String> event, String whatEdited)
{
    if (whatEdited.equals("firstName"))
    {
        event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()).setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
    }
    else if (whatEdited.equals("lastName"))
    {
        event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()).setLastName(event.getNewValue());
    }
    else if (whatEdited.equals("email"))
    {
        event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow()).setEmail(event.getNewValue());
    }
}

private TableColumn<Person, String> createColumn(String title, Function<Person, StringProperty> property)
{
    TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

    col.setCellFactory(column -> new EditCell(property, this.table, this.observableListOfPerson));

    return col;
}

private static class EditCell extends TableCell<Person, String>
{

    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    private final Function<Person, StringProperty> property;

    private TableView table;
    private ObservableList<Person> observableListOfPerson;

    EditCell(Function<Person, StringProperty> property, TableView table, ObservableList<Person> observableListOfPerson)
    {
        this.property = property;
        this.table = table;
        this.observableListOfPerson = observableListOfPerson;

        this.textProperty().bind(this.itemProperty());
        this.setGraphic(this.textField);
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

        this.textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
            this.commitEdit(this.textField.getText());
        });
        this.textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (!isNowFocused)
            {
                this.commitEdit(this.textField.getText());
            }
        });

        // On mouse click event

        this.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> this.handleCellMouseClick(mouseEvent));
    }

    private void handleCellMouseClick(final MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        System.out.println("MOUSE EVENT");

        TableCell<Map<String, SimpleStringProperty>, String> cell = (TableCell<Map<String, SimpleStringProperty>, String>) mouseEvent.getSource();
        int index = cell.getIndex();
        // Set up the map data structure before editing
        this.validCell(index);
        if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
        {
            if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Double clicked on cell");

                final int focusedIndex = this.table.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex();
                if (index == focusedIndex)
                {
                    this.changeTableCellFocus(this.table, index);
                }
            }
            else if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Single click on cell");

                this.changeTableCellFocus(this.table, index);

            }
        }
    }

    private void validCell(final int cellIndex)
    {
        if (cellIndex >= this.observableListOfPerson.size())
        {
            for (int x = this.observableListOfPerson.size(); x <= cellIndex; x++)
            {
                this.observableListOfPerson.add(new Person("", "", ""));

            }
        }
    }

    public void changeTableCellFocus(final TableView<?> table, final int focusIndex)
    {
        table.requestFocus();
        table.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(focusIndex);
        table.getFocusModel().focus(focusIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {
        super.startEdit();
        this.textField.setText(this.getItem());
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        this.textField.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {
        super.cancelEdit();
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(String text)
    {
        super.commitEdit(text);
        Person person = this.getTableView().getItems().get(this.getIndex());
        StringProperty cellProperty = this.property.apply(person);
        cellProperty.set(text);
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

}

public static class Person
{
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email)
    {
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setEmail(email);
    }

    public final StringProperty firstNameProperty()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstNameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName)
    {
        this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
    }

    public final StringProperty lastNameProperty()
    {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getLastName()
    {
        return this.lastNameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName)
    {
        this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
    }

    public final StringProperty emailProperty()
    {
        return this.email;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getEmail()
    {
        return this.emailProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email)
    {
        this.emailProperty().set(email);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Typically if you want information about a cell from a mouse click, you register the mouse listener on the cell. Can you explain more "With a single click nothing happens" (perhaps create a simple, complete example showing the problem). If I register a mouse listener for a click on a table cell, it shows the current focused cell as that cell.

Comment: I can get current selected/focused cell. I can also get the index or the clicked cell. The problem is when I try to change focus to the clicked index cell. It doesn't change focus to the clicked index cell. I think the issue is to do with the fact that the cell is empty. So I've tried adding an object when the cell is clicked. Still same problem.

Comment: Yes, you're pushing the limits of the intended use-case of a `TableView` here. `TableView` is intended as a view of a set of data, which you can manipulate. In that context, it makes no sense to give focus to a cell which is empty, and generally the API doesn't support that. Your workaround (adding new elements to the data model) is a bit problematic: there's no real guarantee that adding new data results in the current cell being used to represent the correct data, due to cell reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
TableCell tc = (TableCell) event.getSource();
int index = tc.getIndex();
```

Comment: I've tried that. The problem with that is it gives the cell that is already focused/selected. I'm trying to get the cell index that has not been selected/focused but the cell that was clicked which in turn triggered the event. The issue here is that its the table click that's triggered the event. There must be a way to get the TableCell that was hovered over when the event was thrown.

Comment: Are you trying to edit a filled cell or edit an empty with single click?

Comment: I was attempting to change focus on a clicked cell (even when the cell is empty i.e. its not clickable). When you click a cell you can get the index regardless of whether its empty or not. The way I've managed to get in kind of working (I don't think its a good way though), listen for a click event. If the cell is empty, add empty data (this could be empty string depending on the data the cell accepts). Then change focus to the clicked cell.